# Ошибка 502 при подключении к smpt серверу yandex

Tags: smtp, яндекс-почта

При подключении к `smpt` серверу `yandex`, и выполнении всех команд для авторизации, после ввода команды `DATA` выдает ошибку 502.

Comment: попробуй у яндекса спросить

Comment: Заглянуть в [документацию по SMTP](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5321#section-4.2.4) не судьба?

Comment: Вообще странный сервер. 

IMHO автор просто не ввел команды MAIL FROM и RCPT TO и по идее должен был получить на DATA код 503 (Bad sequence of commands).

ТС, Вы MAIL и RCPT вводили?